# Unable to make input text field as read only angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

My requirement is to make text field as read only based on a value.
I have tried two ways, both have failed. The following is my code.

Using `ngClass`

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{inputDisabled : data ? true:false}" id="req_name" value={{data.name}}
            name="req_name">
```

Css Code

```
.inputDisabled {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0.4;   }
```

Using readonly

```
    <input [readonly]="data.name === ''? true:false" type="text" value={{data.name}} >
    or
    <input [readonly]="data=== ''? true:false" type="text"  value={{data.name}}>
```

data is a variable which i declare in my component. Initially, in the above cases, data is  `null`, at that time i need to make `textfield` as read-only

Comment: if data is null means it will always go in else condition

Comment: yes now i change to this [ngClass]="{disabledDiv: data ? false:true}". thanks for yor relay @TeParam. Working fine

Comment: I am glad it worked! Please accept an answer if it solves your problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think one of these options could work for you:

```
[readonly]="!data"
```

or

```
[class.inputDisabled]="!data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to compare `data` with the `undefined` so that condition will be true and your input field will get disable based on this condition.

**Example -**

**Using `ngClass`**

```
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{'disabledDiv': !data }" 
    id="requestor_name" value={{data.name}}
    name="requestor_name">
```

**Using `readonly`**

```
<input [readonly]="!data" type="text"  value={{data.name}}>
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine for me

```
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{disabledDiv: data ? false:true}" id="requestor_name" value={{data.name}}
            name="requestor_name">
```

Comment: Can be simplified with  `[ngClass]="{disabledDiv: !!data }"`